# Qt QComboBox,QSpinBox,QGraphicsScene and Gant diagram problem

Tags: c++, qt

I have one problem with the lack of understanding how to make interdependence between QComboBox, QSpinBox and QGraphicsScene, specifically I need to create Gant's dynamic diagram. I need to do the following:

1.Show only elements to fill this number of processes, depending on the selected number of processes (If 5 processes are selected, show only elements to fill out the P1-P5 process).

2.For each process add its QGraphicsRectItem representing the length (number of cycles) of the process duration so that they meet the selected algorithm, guiding the information added to the already mentioned QSpinBox.

The code I created right now looks like this, and also through the dialog. And I added all the elements, if someone had something that could help me, he would be very grateful, thank you in advance.

```
    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox_2;
    //Kreiranje scene
    scene=new QGraphicsScene(this);

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    //Painter,velicina linija i boja
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen mPen;
    mPen.setColor(Qt::blue);
    mPen.setWidth(3);
    painter.setPen(mPen);

    //X linija i strelice
    scene->addLine(-470,50,300,50,mPen);
    scene->addLine(280,70,300,50,mPen);
    scene->addLine(280,30,300,50,mPen);

    //Y linija i strelice
    scene->addLine(-435,-285,-435,85,mPen);
    scene->addLine(-435,-284,-420,-260,mPen);
    scene->addLine(-435,-284,-448,-260,mPen);

    //Text za procese
    QGraphicsTextItem *text1 = scene->addText("Procesi", QFont("Arial", 14));
    text1->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    text1->setPos(-415, -280);

    //Text za broj ciklusa
    QGraphicsTextItem *text2 = scene->addText("Broj ciklusa", QFont("Arial", 14));
    text2->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    text2->setPos(165, 50);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //Text za P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7
    QGraphicsTextItem *pro1 = scene->addText("P1", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro1->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro1->setPos(-467, -260);

    QGraphicsTextItem *pro2 = scene->addText("P2", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro2->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro2->setPos(-467, -215);

    QGraphicsTextItem *pro3 = scene->addText("P3", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro3->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro3->setPos(-467, -170);

    QGraphicsTextItem *pro4 = scene->addText("P4", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro4->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro4->setPos(-467, -125);
    QGraphicsTextItem *pro5 = scene->addText("P5", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro5->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro5->setPos(-467, -80);

    QGraphicsTextItem *pro6 = scene->addText("P6", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro6->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro6->setPos(-467, -35);

    QGraphicsTextItem *pro7 = scene->addText("P7", QFont("Arial", 9));
    pro7->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    pro7->setPos(-467, 10);
}
```

Comment: What output you get from your code??

Comment: I don't understand the question?
I need mostly when I select an item from combobox to show the text under that number I chose if you understand me, I need if statement.

Comment: Are you able to compile and run your code?

Comment: Here's a picture of the run code.
https://prnt.sc/8p0vS90wog1V

Comment: If I understand correctly, the workflow here is to configure a number of items to show in "Broj procesa", enter parameters for those items with the spinboxes, then use the button to update a QGraphicsView?

Comment: I've solved this up here.
Now I need to explain how to make a dynamic QGraphicsRectItem length.
I did this:
Qgraphicsrectitem * re = New QGraphicsRectItem ();
re - > setRect (50,100,50.50);
How now that you select a number on the spinbox to set that length to this QGraphicsRectItem?

Comment: Don't Answer your own question with another question. Just edit the original question with the extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Now I need to explain how to make a dynamic QGraphicsRectItem length. I did this:

```
QGraphicsRectItem *re = new QGraphicsRectItem (); 
re - > setRect (50,100,50,50);
```

How now that you select a number on the spinbox to set that length to this QGraphicsRectItem?

Comment: This should be an edit of the original question. not an answer.